# Unable to traverse a relationship while creating a record

Tags: apex, trigger, formula-field, relationships

I have an object - "training" , which has a master detail relationship with an object - "Employee". I am writting a trigger on training such that when a new training record is created for an employee, it should create an object called "Log" which should copy a field of employee into a field in "Log" object:

```
for(trainig__c training: trigger.new){

List<Log__c> newtransLog = new List<Log__c>();
        Transaction_Log__c log = new Transaction_Log__c(Job_Level_Name__c=training.Employee__r.Job_Level_Name__c);
        newtransLog.add(log);
}
Insert newtransLog;
```

What I am trying to do is - get a value of field from Employee record and assign it to a field in Log record. But this seems to be not working, I am getting a blank value for Job_Level_Name__c  in the Log record

PS - Not sure how I shall query the parent fields inside the for loop? How do I do the query and assignment in this case?

Comment: Not sure how I shall query the parent fields inside the for loop? How do I do the query and assignment in this case?

Comment: It's literally in the [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) doc. See #9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Apex Code Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices):

> ### Best Practice #9: Writing Test Methods to Verify Large Datasets
>
> ...
>
> ```
> trigger contactTest on Contact (before insert, before update) {
>     
>     Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
>     for(Contact ct: Trigger.new)
>         accountIds.add(ct.AccountId);
>     
>     //Do SOQL Query      
>     Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
>         [select id, name, billingState from Account where id in :accountIds]);
>     
>     for(Contact ct: Trigger.new){
>         if(accounts.get(ct.AccountId).BillingState=='CA'){
>             System.debug('found a contact related to an account in california...');
>             ct.email = 'test_email@testing.com';
>             //Apply more logic here....
>         }
>     } 
>     
> }
> ```